# Why the command pattern for implementing Undo and Redo keeps a disposed receiver?

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, undo-redo

I tried to use [Command Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern) for implementing Undo and Redo in my project

```
public abstract class Command
{
    protected Form Receiver { set; get; }
    protected HtmlElement Element { set; get; }
    abstract public void ReDo();
    abstract public void UnDo();
    public Command(Form receiver)
    {
        this.Receiver = receiver;
    }
}
class AddElementCmd : Command
{        
    public AddElementCmd(HtmlElement elem, Form receiver)
        : base(receiver)
    {
        Element = elem;
    }
    public override void ReDo()
    {
        ((FormEdit)Receiver).AddElement(Element,false);
    }
    public override void UnDo()
    {
        ((FormEdit)Receiver).DelElement(Element, false);
    }
}
class DelElementCmd : Command
{
    public DelElementCmd(HtmlElement elem, Form receiver)
        : base(receiver)
    {
        Element = elem;
    }
    public override void ReDo()
    {
        ((FormEdit)Receiver).DelElement(Element, false);
    }
    public override void UnDo()
    {
        ((FormEdit)Receiver).AddElement(Element, false);
    }
}


public void AddElement(HtmlElement elem, bool isNew = true)
{
    IHTMLElement2 dom = elem.DomElement as IHTMLElement2;
    if (isNew)
    {
        Command cmd = new AddElementCmd(elem, this);
        Undo.Push(cmd);
        Redo.Clear();
    }    
    // some codes here....
    if (showAlltoolStripButton.Checked)
    {
        dom.runtimeStyle.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if (showSelectionToolStripButton.Checked)
    {
        dom.runtimeStyle.visibility = "visible";
    }
 }
...
```

the `Undo` and `Redo` lists are stored in the `FormMain` class and are passed to the editor form.

```
FormEdit editor = new FormEdit ();
editor.Browser = webBrowser1;
editor.addedElements = addedElements;
editor.restoreElements = restoreElements;
editor.Undo = Undo;
editor.Redo = Redo;

editor.ShowDialog();


editor.Dispose();
GC.Collect();
```

When in a new edit form the user clicks on Redo or Undo button, the function in the `EditForm` is executed, but as I checked this receiver of the command is the form in which the command was first created and now may has been disposed. I expect that the class raise an error, but it seems the `Command` object stores a reference to it and these lead to misbehavior. For example when the `toolStripButton` is checked  and I click undo button, (or redo), at the debug, the break point in the function shows the button.Checked is false (while it is true, and UI shows it is checked) !!! this button should be the button on the form that the command belongs to?

I solved the problem by setting the `Receiver` after I popped a command from the stack.

Now my question is why the closed and disposed forms are still valid for the `Command` object? I even explicitly disposed the `FormEdit` and called the garbage collect in the main form, but still the command object executes the code for that form.

Comment: It is a pretty plain bug, you don't store the state of the button.  Your Undo() must restore the state of the button it had when the command was added.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't want the command work according to the state of button when the command was added, but according to the current state of the button, and when it is obviously true, and UI shows it is checked, I don't see how it is `false` inside the function.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `DelElement`? I suspect you have a bug in the manipulation of states of the `toolStripButton`.

Comment: I think the Command behaviour here is a bit skewed.  Your add element command SHOULD _add element on redo/action_ and _delete element on undo_.  Your delete element command SHOULD _delete element on redo/action_ and _add element on undo_.  They *should* have no knowledge of the button state.

Comment: @Ruskin you are right, but how can I get notified that the element has been removed or added in order to update the view?

Comment: Depends, do you want to be notified from a business perspective or from a UI perspective?  From a business perspective you can simply add an event on the command and fire it on Undo/Redo.  From UI perspective you can simply hook into the ****_Changed events of the control.  Does that help?

Comment: @Ruskin thanks, you are right, however for undo and redo many times we need to update the view and I think it is not such bad to update it in the associated functions, but my problem was that I haven't changed the `Reciever` of the `Command` object when the edit form closes and opens.

Comment: @HansPassant I found the source of bug, which was a disposed form for the popped command, but I don't know why it is still valid for the command object!